# get ion-select selected option

Tags: angular, ionic2

I"m trying to get the value from a select element in ionic,
here is the code below:

```
<ion-content padding style="direction:rtl;">
  <ion-list>
    <ion-item>
      <ion-label>בחר מטבע:</ion-label>
      <ion-select #selectCurrencyInput okText="אשר" cancelText="בטל" ionChange="alert(this.value)">
        <ion-option value="BGN">BGN</ion-option>
        <ion-option value="BRL">BRL</ion-option>
        <ion-option value="CAD">CAD</ion-option>
        <ion-option value="CHF">CHF</ion-option>
        <ion-option value="CNY">CNY</ion-option>
        <ion-option value="CZK">CZK</ion-option>
        <ion-option value="DKK">DKK</ion-option>
        <ion-option value="GBP">GBP</ion-option>
        <ion-option value="HKD">HKD</ion-option>
        <ion-option value="HRK">HRK</ion-option>
        <ion-option value="HUF">HUF</ion-option>
        <ion-option value="IDR">IDR</ion-option>
        <ion-option value="ILS">ILS</ion-option>
        <ion-option value="INR">INR</ion-option>
        <ion-option value="JPY">JPY</ion-option>
        <ion-option value="KRW">KRW</ion-option>
        <ion-option value="MXN">MXN</ion-option>
        <ion-option value="MYR">MYR</ion-option>
        <ion-option value="NOK">NOK</ion-option>
        <ion-option value="NZD">NZD</ion-option>
        <ion-option value="PHP">PHP</ion-option>
        <ion-option value="ZAR">ZAR</ion-option>
        <ion-option value="PLN">PLN</ion-option>
        <ion-option value="RON">RON</ion-option>
        <ion-option value="RUB">RUB</ion-option>
        <ion-option value="SEK">SEK</ion-option>
        <ion-option value="SGD">SGD</ion-option>
        <ion-option value="THB">THB</ion-option>
        <ion-option value="TRY">TRY</ion-option>
        <ion-option value="USD">USD</ion-option>
      </ion-select>
    </ion-item>
    <ion-item>
      <ion-label>כמות לחישוב</ion-label>
      <ion-input #amountCurrencyInput type="text"></ion-input>
    </ion-item>
    <ion-item>
      <button ion-button (click)="calc(
        {
          selectedCurrency:selectCurrencyInput.value,
          amountCurrency:amountCurrencyInput.value
        })">חשב מטבע</button>
    </ion-item>
  </ion-list>
</ion-content>
```

as you can see I mark the ion-select as `#selectCurrencyInput`
and send it to the function calc in object.

I am trying to get its value using the function `.value`, 
and the result is undefined, I get the value of the `ion-input` so I guess something is wrong in the ion-select or I dont understand it.

THX :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try binding to a var on the model in ion-select:

```
<ion-select [(ngModel)]="toppings" multiple="true">
```

Comment: I should mention the multiple attr is only if you want to allow multiple selections.

Comment: yes ofcourse i know that :) 
maybe you can help me here, 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40295981/read-json-using-angular2?noredirect=1#comment67859291_40295981

Answer (score 0):

ion-select works just like the select does. You have to bind a model with the select element that will bind your selected option's value